# How can I make this MOD-5 counter work (vhdl)?

Tags: vhdl, counter

I'm trying to implement a MOD-5 counter in VHDL and I've tried using the following steps:

- I created a `GENERIC` N bit counter
- Then I instantiated a 3 bit counter
- Using the 3 bit counter as a `COMPONENT` I reset the Count to 0 when it reaches 4

I've tested it and it's not working, the Count signal stays Undefined for the whole simulation. Can anyone solve this problem?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY counter_n_bit IS
GENERIC(
    N : INTEGER);
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    -- Clear is a synchronous reset
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : BUFFER UNSIGNED(N - 1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END counter_n_bit;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF counter_n_bit IS

BEGIN

    PROCESS(Clock)
    BEGIN
        -- since this is a synchronous circuit, signal should
        -- only change on clock's edges. I chose rising edges.
        IF Clock'EVENT AND Clock = '1' THEN
            -- if clear is set to 1, no matter the other signals, the counter resets
            -- same if it got to the max integer that can be represented on N bits (2^N - 1)
            IF Clear = '1' OR Count = 2**N - 1 THEN
                Count <= (OTHERS => '0');
            ELSE
            -- if none of this condtions are satisfied we're in the regular case
            -- and I update the Count value incrementing it by one
                IF Enable = '1' THEN
                    Count <= Count + 1;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

END behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY counter_3_bit IS
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : OUT UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END counter_3_bit;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF counter_3_bit IS

COMPONENT counter_n_bit 
GENERIC(
    N : INTEGER);
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : OUT UNSIGNED(N - 1 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    -- instantiation of a 3 bit counter
    counter_3: counter_n_bit GENERIC MAP (N => 3) PORT MAP (Clock => Clock, Enable => Enable, Clear => Clear, Count => Count);

END behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY counter_3_bit_5 IS
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : BUFFER UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END counter_3_bit_5;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF counter_3_bit_5 IS

COMPONENT counter_3_bit 
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : OUT UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    -- instantiation of a 3 bit counter
    counter_3: counter_3_bit PORT MAP (Clock => Clock, Enable => Enable, Clear => Clear, Count => Count);
    
    PROCESS (Count)
    
    BEGIN

        IF Count = "100" THEN
            Count <= "000";
        END IF;

    END PROCESS;


END behaviour;
```

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY tb_counter_3_bit_5 IS
END tb_counter_3_bit_5;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF tb_counter_3_bit_5 IS

COMPONENT counter_3_bit_5 
PORT(
    Clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Clear : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Count : BUFFER UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL Clock_tb, Clear_tb, Enable_tb : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL Count_tb : UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN

    Clear_tb <= '1', '0' AFTER 6 ns;
    Enable_tb <= '1';

    clk_process: PROCESS
    BEGIN
        Clock_tb <= '0';
        WAIT FOR 5 ns;
        Clock_tb <= NOT Clock_tb;
        WAIT FOR 5 ns;
    END PROCESS;
    -- instantiation of a 3 bit counter
    dut: counter_3_bit_5 PORT MAP (Clock => Clock_tb, Enable => Enable_tb, Clear => Clear_tb, Count => Count_tb);

END behaviour;
```

Comment: "... the Count signal stays Undefined for the whole simulation." In counter_3_bit_5 there are two drivers for Count, Counter_3's Count output and the unlabelled process Count assignment. The value of Count will be the resolution of both of these. There's potentially more issues, your code isn't minimal for the problem.

Comment: How can I improve it? Should I delete the counter_3_bit and directly make the counter_3_bit_5?

Comment: All assignments to Count should be in one process.

Comment: Ok! I'm trying it now. If I have other issues I update this question.